# Solr doesn't index blob files

Tags: solr, blob, plone, zodb, blobstorage

I am using the Collective Solr 4.1.0 Search on our Plone 4.2.6 system.

My issue now is the following. On our Plone Server, we use `ZODB` for creating blob files. When I now try to build an index in Solr, I get the error `INFO UniCMSData MISSING BLOB FILE: /opt/plone/data/blobstorage/0x31/0x37/0x32/0x36/0x39/0xa2/0xce/0x3e/0x03b3d7af6465c4cc.blob`.

The path looks proper to me and I know that unter `opt/plone/data/blobstorage` all blob files are stored. That makes me wonder: Did Solr not find it or is just something awfully wrong with my Solr Configuration? Or does Solr not handle ZODB blobs properly?

Greatful for every little help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's me again :-)

No nothing is wrong with yout solr configuration.

Solr ships with a[pache tika](https://tika.apache.org/) by default, which can convert nearly everything to text/plain.

But you need at least `collective.solr` 5.0.1, because with this version it's possible to extract the searchable text directly from the blob using the `collective.solr BinaryIndexer`.

If you're unable to upgrade your plone site / collective.solr you may install `ftw.tika` --> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftw.tika/2.7.0

`ftw.tika` registers a plone `portal_transforms`, which uses tika to convert many types to plain/text. You can run tika also as service.

`ftw.tika` is Plone 4.2 compatible.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me here :)
I'll check if apache tika will do it for me. Is it completely useless for this task with a `collective.solr` version of less than 5.0.1?

Comment: Before collective.solr 5.0.1 there were issues with indexing blobs directly... like solr tried to index the file before it was actually written to the disk.

Comment: I upgraded our collective.solr to 5.0.3 now. So far, it looks really good and I didn't encounter the `BlobError` anymore. I'll get back to this thread when the reindexing is done, but I'm already very optimistic :)

Comment: I've been testing for quite a bit and it works like a charm :) Still running into some errors along my way, but for indexing images and files the upgrade saved me a whole lot of work. Thank you very much for your help!